# Randomly reposition jQuery UI dialog (easter egg)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am currently implementing an easter egg feature in my application. Whenever the user hovers over a jQuery UI close button, the dialog div should randomly reposition (so the user can't close it).

Here is what i tried so far:

```
$('.ui-icon-closethick').hover(function() {
    console.log("hover");

    $('#trollDialog').dialog('option', 'position', 
        [randomX, randomY]
    );
});
```

Unfortunately the dialog doesn't reposition at all. How can i reposition the dialog with absolute x and y positions?

Comment: What are the values for randomX and randomY? Where do they come from?

Comment: This is not the way the [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option works.

Comment: @j08691 doesn't matter, I just want to set any absolute value (in pixels) as the position.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi then would you be so kind and tell me how, please?

Comment: @j08691 so is there no way to pass absolute values in pixles?

Comment: @LDC, as you can see if you follow the link I have posted, you cannot use the `position` option to specify the exact pixel coordinates the dialog should be positioned to. There is no provision for this feature in the widget itself, you would have to extend it with your behavior. *If* the widget's root element is absolutely positioned, you may get away with manipulating its `left` and `top` CSS properties.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sry, I didn't see the link in your comment. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Providing random coordinates *should* work. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/54cemw65/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick working example:

```js
$("#dialog").dialog();
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hover(function () {
    var randomPos = "left" + (Math.random() * 10 < 5 ? "-" : "+") + Math.random() * 100 + " " + "top" + (Math.random() * 10 < 5 ? "-" : "+") + Math.random() * 100;
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", { my: randomPos });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Hover to Move"></div>
```

You have to set the offset from the `left` and `top` properties if you are going to use jQuery-UI's `position`

**Note: The snippet works better if you view "Full Page"**

Comment: Yor solutions all worked, but this answer also provided the right jqery-ui lib. My used jQuery ui version was appearantly too old. Props to @Mackan for giving a nice way of randomisation.

Answer (score 0):

Not absolute positioning, but you [can do relative](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/):

```
$('.ui-icon-closethick').hover(function(e) {
    var newPos = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? "left-" : "right-") +
                 (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)) + " " +
                 (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? "bottom-" : "top-") +
                 (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    $( "#trollDialog" ).dialog( "option", "position", { 
        my: newPos
    });
});
```

Not perfect randomization, but an example anyway